# Referencing parent field on document creation

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a form called `ProductFamily`.
It has a field called `ProductFamilyMBValues` which is a list of strings.

I've got a response document using a form called `Item`, which is always a response of a document using the above form.

The `Item` form has a `dialoglist` field `ItemMakeBuy` that has the validation formula `@If(@Length(ItemMakeBuy) = 0;@Failure("You must choose a Make or Buy value");@Success)`

The choices for that field is a formula: `@IfError(@GetDocField($ref;"ProductFamilyMBValues");"?")`.

My problem is that when i create a new `Item` document the choices for the `ItemMakeBuy` field aren't populated, seemingly because until the document is saved the `$ref` field isn't populated. However, i can't save it because of my validation formula, requiring a value to be entered.

How can i get around this issue? Ideally i want to keep the validation formula for the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the response, do you copy any other fields from the parent? If you copy the UniversalID to the response you can use that until the document is saved. If combined with a `@IsNewDoc` in the formula, the moment  the document is saved it can point to the $REF.

Or something like this: @IfError(@GetDocField($ref;"ProductFamilyMBValues");@GetDocField(ParentUNIDField;"ProductFamilyMBValues"))

Comment: What do you mean by 'copy any other fields from the parent'? How would i copy the UNID to the respnose?

Comment: One way to copy it is the method Ken mentioned in his answer. If you create the response using formula or script I would add it there.

Comment: I'm creating it using a form action with the formula  `@Command([Compose];"";"Item")`, how could i set a field of that newly created document. I'm guessing `@SetField` would effect the current document.

Comment: A copy of the universalid in an item on the parent could be used if available. In that case just use a computed-when-composed field on the response with the name of the item on the parent. I am not sure if the universalid can be inherite straight from the parent. Maybe it is easier to program this in lotusscript to maintain the control.

Comment: Welcome. @InheritedDocumentUniqueID is the formula by the way

Answer (score 1):

That is a logical way to reference the parent document, but Notes has an alternate way to get at parent field information.  In your Item form, go to the form properties and select the option "on create: formulas inherit values from selected document".  Then you can create any number of fields in the `Item` form and use a computed field formula referencing the field name from the `ProductFamily` form, and those values will get passed in.  In your case, you could just pass the ProductFamilyMBValues field to the response doc.

Here is [more information](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_CREATING_FIELDS_THAT_INHERIT_VALUES.html) on that subject from the docs.

Comment: I understand that i can use `formulas inherit values from selected document`, however, i want the values to be updated if the parent document values changes (without having to add extra code if i can). I also don't want all the parent's fields polluting the response form.

Comment: Makes sense.  A combination of using this method to get the parentUNID over to the response doc, and then using that in your formula to retrieve the values via @GetDocField, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `@InheritedDocumentUniqueID` to get the parent doc id when creating a new doc.

In your case the formula for the choices would be :
    `@IfError(@GetDocField(@InheritedDocumentUniqueID;"ProductFamilyMBValues");"?")`