# Formula referencing parent doc works in computed field, not as default value

Tags: parent, lotus-notes, default-value, lotus-formula

Following on from this question: [Referencing parent field on document creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660665/referencing-parent-field-on-document-creation) I'm using the formula for the default value for a `name` field.

```
IfError(@IfError(@GetDocField($ref;"ProductFamilyManager");
                 @GetDocField(ParentUNID;"ProductFamilyManager"));
        "")
```

This works when it's a computed field, but not when i change it to be editable with a default value formula.

Any ideas how I can get the field populating with the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to use @InheritedDocumentUniqueId.  You need to enable inheritance to make that function available, but you don't actually have to inherit any of the parent values.

You should definitely not have to be using two different techniques and @IfError to get this done.  And btw: did you know that @IfError is obsolete as of Domino 7?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be supported but just to be sure, has the parent doc been saved before you create the response doc?

Assuming that's not the problem, the alternative is to use the "inherit field values from parent doc " option, which will pass a value from the parent doc to the response doc on creation.  I may have the wording wrong but the option is on the form properties dialog in Designer.

Comment: Yes, the parent document has been saved already. If i did inherit values from the parent doc would it inherit all values? Wouldn't it be hard to determine what was what?

Comment: It only inherits values for fields that contain a parent doc fieldname in their formula.